# javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create queue session

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

When I try this in multi-threaded context it is working properly.

```java
final QueueSession session=con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

When I try the same in a try/catch block it works sometimes:

```java
QueueSession session = null;
try {
   session= con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
} catch(Exception) {

} finally {

}
```

But sometimes it throws an exception like:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create queue session
```

[image]

Could you please help ?
Thanks,